# Tensorflow CNN Shape error

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tf-slim

I'm trying to use a CNN on some data but I'm getting an error in my loss function since the output of my model is the shape [1000, 1000, 4000] when it should be [1000, 4000]. The first 1000 in this case is the batch size, and the 4000 is the number of classes that I have since this is a classification problem.

I think I may need to use the tf.reshape() function again after my fully_connected layer to get the right output but I'm not quite sure how I can do that. I already tried tf.reshape(output [-1, 4000]), but that still keeps the other 1000 inside.

Here is my code:

```
    cnn_input = tf.reshape(input, [-1, 1000, 1])
    net = slim.conv2d(cnn_input, 128, [3])
    net = slim.pool(net, [2], "MAX")
    output = slim.fully_connected(net, num_classes, activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax)
    return output
```

Basically, my output needs to be a shape of rank 2, but for some reason it's turning out to have 3 dimensions. I need the output to be of shape [1000, 4000], which is batch size x num_classes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

By the way, I am using the tf-slim library.

EDIT: Would tf.flatten work for this before the fully_connected layer?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error. The [documentation (line 1609)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py) (as linked from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim)) indicates that the 'fully_connected' operation is supposed to flatten the output, but it doesn't. I just used slim.flatten before the last couple fully connected operations as you suggested, but I have no concrete evidence that it works yet.

With 6 months of no comments, I thought something would better than nothing for others, but if anybody else has more insights, it would be appreciated.